# VRM model in blender: Transparent overhang

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, vertex-weights, knife-tool

I have been trying to work on a Quest version of an avatar recently in blender, and it's a VRM file, and because VRM textures can be cut in VRoid, vertices are left around the textures that extend out from where the texture actually is.

I have seen people talk about using the *Knife Tool* in Blender, and I have tried to use it, but for some reason the vertices stretch down after I cut them when I try using *Blendshapes* on them. I even messed around a bit with weight painting the eyelashes and eyebrows to the head, but it doesn't appear to work either. Does anyone know what I can do to get rid of the unnecessary vertices correctly?

[image: Blendshapes stretching]